# Converting String to Time without Date in Java

Tags: java, date

How to convert String to Time in java without Date,I need specifically the time alone

```
String Start_time="04:30";
```

I used

```
 DateFormat time=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
 Time bid_start_time=new Time(time.parse("Start_time").getTime());
```

I exactly need the value "04:30" in Date format.I don't need the extra Date parameters like DD/MM/YY

Comment: `LocalTime.parse("04:30"); `...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have a `Date` without the calendar date parts. That's a simple fact of what `Date` represents:

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.
>   ...
>   represent[s] the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

You can use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)), or [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) from [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) otherwise. These classes represent a time-of-day without a date nor a time zone.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("04:30");
```

You *could* prepend the time string with "1970-01-01 ", and then parse e.g. "1970-01-01 04:30", and then just take care to use the time parts of this.  I would recommend against that because of the potential not just to use it for only its time parts.